# xcode 4.1 leaks memory

Tags: memory-leaks, xcode4, clang, xcode4.1

I recently upgraded to mac OS X Lion and installed Xcode 4.1. I have noticed, at least on my machines, that Xcode, more specifically libclang.dylib, is leaking a lot of memory (ex. see screen shot of Instruments). I also did a fresh install and reinstalled Xcode and it does the same thing. I am wondering if other people are having this problem and is there a way I can temporarily patch this (ex. disable clang, etc.)? thanks in advance[image: screenshot of insruments showing the memory leaks]

Comment: The longer I leave Xcode 4 running, the more it misbehaves. I end up quitting and re-launching it several times a day. :-) Report bugs to http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Yeah I have the same issue... Xcode can end up using more than 5G of memory. That's usually when I decide to relaunch it :)